# Parent element ID and full element path as result of Xpath query on XMLTYPE table

Tags: oracle, xpath, xquery, xmltype

I need help with xpath search in xmltype table:

```
create table TOPOLOGY of xmltype
xmltype store as SECUREFILE BINARY XML
xmlschema "topology.xsd"
element "root";
```

topology.xsd defines XML structure as  element containing nested  elements. Every  element has 'id', 'name' and 'type' attributes. Every item may contain 0..* child items.

Table contains always single row (single xml). I need to search for specific items using xpath queries and return refcursor containing following data (for matching elements):

- attribute values
- id attribute of parent item element
- absolute path (/root/item[...]/.../item[...])

I was only able to return attribute values, but it was impossible for me to get the other two requirements. My current solution is:

```
procedure search_tree(xpath in varchar2, output out sys_refcursor) as
begin
  open output for
    select *
    from TOPOLOGY t, xmltable(
        '*' passing t.extract(xpath)
        columns
            id varchar2(255) path '@id',
            name varchar2(255) path '@name',
            type_name varchar2(255) path '@type',
        );
END search_tree;
```

Here, on SO, I've found a solution for obtaining parent node using XQuery:

```
select *
from TOPOLOGY t, xmltable(
'for $i in $xp let $parentId := $i/../@id
return <r id="{$i/@id}" name="{$i/@name}" typeId="{$i/@type}" parentId="{$parentId}" />'
passing t.object_value, xpath as "xp"
columns id varchar2(255) path '@id', name varchar2(255) path '@name', type varchar2(255) path '@type', parent_xid varchar2(255) path '@parentId');
```

but the xpath passed the the $xp variable is causing problems and the code does not work.
I've found no way how to get full path to found elements. To summarize all this, I need to find a way, how to:

- return 'id' attribute of parent item
- return full path to the matching elements

Thank you in advance.

Adam

Comment: Having the same problem. Using `id varchar2(255) path './../@id'` work in pure select statement but not in plsql statement.